# Modifying options for particular class under automodule directive

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext, autodoc

I have a Python module, `my_module.py`, that looks like this:

```py
import numpy

class A(numpy.ndarray):
    """ Extension for illustration. """
    pass

class B:
    """ My base class. """
    def x():
        """ Does the thing. """
        pass

class C(B):
    """ My extension class. """
    pass
```

I have a reST file that looks like this:

```
API Reference
=============

my_module
---------

.. automodule:: my_module
    :members:
    :special_members:
```

I would like to be able to add an `:inherited-members:` option to `B` and `C`, but not `A`.

I have attempted to add individual `autoclass` directives under the `automodule`:

```
.. automodule:: my_module
   :members:
   :special_members:

   .. autoclass:: B
      :inherited-members:

   .. autoclass:: C
      :inherited-members:
```

This has the unintended effect of placing a correctly documented version of `B` and `C`, with inherited members, followed by the full documentation of `A`, `B`, `C`, all without inherited members in the same file.

How do I specify different options for some of the members without duplicating the generated documentation?

I am using Sphinx 1.6.3 on an Anaconda install of Python 3.6.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `:members:` to classes `B` and `C` and `:exclude-members: B, C` to the module:

```
.. automodule:: my_module
   :members:
   :special_members:
   :exclude-members: B, C

   .. autoclass:: B
      :inherited-members:
      :members:

   .. autoclass:: C
      :inherited-members:
      :members:
```

From [`automodule`, `autoclass`, and `autoexception` options and advanced usage](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/autodoc.html#directive-automodule):

> For classes and exceptions, members inherited from base classes will be left out when documenting all members, unless you give the `inherited-members` flag option, in addition to `members`:
>
> ```
> .. autoclass:: Noodle
>    :members:
>    :inherited-members:
> ```

If that doesn't work, I can refine my Answer. Comments are not good for providing sample code, so I have to use an Answer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on https://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/sphinx.html#full-code-example, it appears that one way to prevent duplication of documentation is to add an explicit list to the `automodule` option `:members:`:

```
.. automodule:: my_module
    :members: A
    :special_members:

   .. autoclass:: B
      :inherited-members:

   .. autoclass:: C
      :inherited-members:
```

The only problem here is that the nested `autoclass` elements (`B`, `C`) are rendered before the bulk of the remainder of the module (`A`), which is not exactly what I want.

The solution is to either un-nest the `autoclass` directives:

```
.. automodule:: my_module
    :members: A
    :special_members:

.. autoclass:: B
   :members:
   :inherited-members:

.. autoclass:: C
   :members:
   :inherited-members:
```

Providing two `automodule` directives, each with a different set of options and different explicit lists of members **does not work**. The result is a warning stating that

```
WARNING: Duplicate ID: "my_module".
```

The options for both of the `automodule` directives are combined, making the separation pointless.

Placing an `autoclass` before an `automodule` for the module that contains it causes a similar problem. The class documentation will be rendered twice: once with the options in the `autoclass`, and once with the options in the `automodule`.

**UPDATE**

It *is* in fact possible to place an `automodule` directive after an `autoclass` from the same module with correct behavior if an `:exclude-members:` option appears in the `automodule`:

```
.. autoclass:: my_module.A
   :members:
   :special-members:

.. automodule:: my_module
   :members: B, C
   :exclude-members: A
   :inherited-members:
```

This is convenient if the majority of members should appear last but does not require special handling.

It turns out that using the `:exclude-members:` option also works for the nested case:

```
.. automodule:: my_module
   :members:
   :exclude-members: A
   :inherited-members:

   .. autoclass:: my_module.A
      :members:
      :special-members:
```

None of the options are inherited by the nested `automodule`, so the only differences from the example in the original question are the added `:exclude-members:` in `automodule` and `:members:` in `autoclass`.

Technically this means that doing `automodule` twice is possible as well:

```
.. automodule:: my_module
   :members:
   :exclude-members: B, C
   :special-members:

.. automodule:: my_module
   :members:
   :exclude-members: A
   :inherited-members:
```

This option is not particularly desirable, however, because it causes a warning and requires a listing of the inverse set of the members we want to document, making it much less intuitive.